# How to define more than one mongo port in a redhat server?

Tags: mongodb, redhat

I have one amazon linux server where someone installed mongodb.

So netstat -tulpn is showing 2 ports open for mongod process one is default 27017 and other is 37017 but i am not getting in which file he mentioned these ports, My /etc/mongod.conf showing only default port 27017 only.

Any suggestion please...

Comment: Is it possible that there are two instances of mongodb running. Each using a different port?